# Period of the pendulum (realistic) is shortening in time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, measurements, anharmonic-oscillators

I am doing an experiment with a pendulum and am trying to measure its period over time. I built myself a contraption that uses a 3D printed pendulum with a weight attached at the end. [image]

For this experiment, I am using an IR sensor connected to the Arduino UNO board. The IR sensor is mounted on the bottom plate and measures the time difference between swings of the pendulum. For some reason, once the pendulum starts swinging, I see a decreasing period.

[image]

Can anybody help me understand why this might be? As far as I understand, the period for this pendulum should be increasing from damping.

I am also providing the Arduino code that I am using. This code registers every other swing to compensate for the sensor not being in the exact middle.

```
#define IR_PIN 2 // Pin connected to the IR sensor
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY 10000 // Debounce delay in milliseconds

volatile unsigned long previousDetection = 0;
volatile bool isHigh = false; // Flag to track IR sensor state

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(IR_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // Set IR pin as input with pull-up resistor
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(IR_PIN), ISR_handler, CHANGE); // Attach interrupt on pin change
}

void loop() {
  // Nothing to do here, interrupt handler takes care of everything
}

void ISR_handler() {
  unsigned long currentTime = micros();
  
  // Debounce logic
  if (currentTime - previousDetection >= DEBOUNCE_DELAY) {
    isHigh = !digitalRead(IR_PIN); // Update state and debounce
    
    if (isHigh) { // Rising edge (pendulum passing sensor)
      static unsigned long previousRisingEdgeTime = 0;
      unsigned long period = currentTime - previousRisingEdgeTime;
      previousRisingEdgeTime = currentTime;
      
      static int count = 0;
      count++;
      if (count % 2 == 1) { // Every other detection (odd count)
        Serial.println(period); // Print period
      }
    }
    
    previousDetection = currentTime;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody help me understand why this might be? As far as I understand, the period for this pendulum should be increasing from damping.

You are wrong. [As a pendulum damps to a smaller amplitude of oscillation, it gets faster, i.e. shorter periods.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period) So what you are seeing is probably expected and correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The period of a pendulum is only independent of its amplitude if you use the small-angle-approximation $\sin(x) \approx x$ when calculating its period. This approximation, as one might expect form its name, works reasonably well for small angles, but not for bigger angles or if you're measuring precisely.

Without the approximation, the period becomes longer for higher angles. This makes intuitive sense if you consider that the force pulling on the pendulum is proportional to $\sin(x)$, which is always less than $x$ as assumed in the approximation, and the discrepancy only grows for larger angles.

The period without the approximation is given by $$T = T_0 \frac{2}{\pi}K\left(\sin\left(\frac{\theta_0}{2}\right)\right)$$ where $T_0$ is the period you'd get using the approximation, $\theta_0$ is the angle at maximal displacement and K is a mathematical function known as complete elliptical integral of the first kind. [(Source: the Wikipedia article on pendulums)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period)

We can use this formula to approximate the angle your pendulum swung at right at the beginning. Reading of a starting period of 502 ms and assuming the lowest measured period of about 489 ms corresponds to the period for small angles, I calculate a roughly approximate angle of 8° for the initial amplitude.

Comment: I have tried to use the small angle approximation, I am trying to start the pendulum within 5° from the resting position.

Comment: from my math, it looks like you might be starting at a bit more than 5°. But using the formula given in my answer, at 5° you would still get a period that is about 1.1% longer than expected from the small angle approximation.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might be causing the period to be shorter? I have tried to do the test one more time, making sure to have max 5° from resting position but I got the same results, the period is getting shorter.

Comment: it definitely should be getting shorter, even if you start from only 5° degrees. The difference between beginning and end should however be less than it is in the data you posted. Perhaps there's another effect I can't think of

Comment: Ohh, thats how you meant the answer. Sorry, I misunderstood. So my initial thought that the period should be getting longer is wrong.